# how to stay in current page after refreshing the page in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I am new to angularjs and I have created a login page.

Once I logined it will redirect to my home page. when i click on refresh button it is not staying in current page it is going to login page.

Please can anyone help me.

Thanks in advance.

The below is my code i wrote

**login.view.html**

```
<div class="page-wrapper">
    <div class="main-wrapper bgm">
        <div class="main">
            <div class= "document-title"></div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class=" row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-8">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading"><div class="logo text-center"><strong>Login</strong></div></div>


        <div class="panel-body">
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="personal">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <form name="form" ng-submit="vm.login()" role="form">
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.username.$dirty && form.username.$error.required }">
            <label for="username">Email/UserName</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email/UserName" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.username" required />
            <span ng-show="form.username.$dirty && form.username.$error.required" class="help-block">Email or username required</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.password.$dirty && form.password.$error.required }">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password" ng-model="vm.password" required />
            <span ng-show="form.password.$dirty && form.password.$error.required" class="help-block">Password  required</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
             <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
                  <div class="checkbox"><label class=""><input type="checkbox" class="">Remember me</label></div>
             </div>
        </div>        
        <div class="form-actions">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
            <button type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid || vm.dataLoading" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Sign in</button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Reset</button>
            <img ng-if="vm.dataLoading" src="data:image/gif;base64,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" />

             </div>
           </div>
         </form>
       </div>       
    </div><!-- /.row -->
  </div><!-- /.tab-pane -->
</div><!-- panel body -->

                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        <div class="row">
                            <a href="#/resetpassword" class="btn btn-link">Forgot Password?</a>
                        </div><!-- row -->
                    </div><!-- panel footer -->
                  </div><!-- /.tab-panel default -->
                </div> <!--col-md-4-->
             </div><!-- /.row -->
          </div><!-- /.container -->
        </div><!-- /.main -->
    </div><!-- /.main-wrapper -->
</div><!-- /.page-wrapper -->
```

**home.view.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
    <head>
    <title>Groupz</title>
    </head>
    <style>
        /* Remove the navbar's default margin-bottom and rounded borders */

        .navbar {
            margin-bottom: 0;
            border-radius: 0;
            border-color: white;
            height: 6em;
            padding-top: 12px;
            background-color: #2eb2f2;
        }
        /* Set height of the grid so .sidenav can be 100% (adjust as needed) */

        .row.content {
            height: 1000px
        }
        /* Set gray background color and 100% height */

        .sidenav {
            padding-top: 20px;
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
            height: 100%;
        }
        /* Set black background color, white text and some padding */

        footer {
            background-color: #555;
            color: white;
            padding: 15px;
        }
        /* On small screens, set height to 'auto' for sidenav and grid */

       @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
            .sidenav {
                height: auto;
                padding: 15px;
            }
            .row.content {
                height: auto;
            }
        }

        canvas {
            padding: 0 30px 0 0;
        }
    </style>

<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <img class="img-responsive" src="css/images/Groupz.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">

        <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="padding-top:6px;">
        <div class="dropdown">
        <span class="badge">5</span><img style="padding-right:10px;" src="css/images/bell1.png" />
        <img class="img-circle dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" width="40" height="40" src="css/images/image.jpg" /><span class="caret dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"></span>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#/login">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid text-center" ng-controller="UserDataController as ctrl">

     <div class="row content" style="margin-top:100px; color:rgba(51, 122, 183, 1);" ng-if="!model.displayHome">
        <button ng-click="getData('json.json','','','GET')">Click to login</button>
    </div>


        <div class="row content" ng-if="model.displayHome">
            <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
        <div class="well well-lg col-xs-30" style="background-color: green;" ng-show="true">

        <img class="img-responsive" style="padding-bottom:10px;" src="css/images/image.jpg" />
        <div class="form-group"> 
           <select class="form-control" ng-model="model.selectedValue" name="groupzname"> 
               <option value='' disabled> Switch Account </option>
                 <option ng-repeat="item in model.dropDownData track by $index" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
                   </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#/dashboard"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard vmenu"></span>  Dashboard</a>
      </li>
      <li class="#/Profile"><a href="#/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user vmenu"></span>Profile</a>
      </li>
         <li><a href="#/Account"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit vmenu"></span>Account</a>
      </li>
         <li><a href="#/Dropbox"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tags vmenu"></span>Dropbox</a>
      </li>
         <li><a href="#/Checklist"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off vmenu"></span>Checklist</a>
      </li>
        <li><a href="#/Report"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off vmenu"></span>Report</a>
      </li>
        <li><a href="#/Settings"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off vmenu"></span>Settings</a>
      </li>
        <li><a href="#/Help"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off vmenu"></span>Help</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-8 text-left" ng-show="true"> 
      <h1>Welcome</h1>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label class="form-control" ng-model="model.membervalue" name="membername" style="border:none"> {{model.membervalue}}</label>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
     </div>
<footer class="container-fluid text-center">
  <p>Groupz</p>
</footer>


</body>

</html>
```

**userdata.controller.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('app');
app.controller('UserDataController', function($scope,$window,$http,$q) {
       $scope.model = { 
    'displayHome' : false,
    'dropDownData':[]
       };


       $scope.cookietechnology = $window.localStorage.x; //getting data from cookies

       if($scope.cookietechnology){

        $scope.model.dropDownData  = $scope.cookietechnology;
        $scope.model.selectedValue = $scope.cookietechnology;
        $scope.model.displayHome =  true;

    }


     $scope.getData = function(requestedUrl,requestHeader, requestData,requestMethod) {
    $scope.model.dropDownData = [];
                 var deferred = $q.defer();
                 var req = {
                     method: requestMethod,
                     url: requestedUrl,
                     headers:{"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
                     data: requestData
                 };

             $http(req)
                     .success(function(response) {
                 var user = response.json.response.user;
                 console.log(user);
          for(var i=0; i<user.length-1; i++)
          { 
                 console.log("datas : "+response.json.response.user[i].groupzname);
            $scope.model.dropDownData.push(response.json.response.user[i].groupzname + " - "+response.json.response.user[i].membername); // we can itterate and set the drop down values
              console.log($scope.model.dropDownData);
            $scope.model.selectedValue = response.json.response.user[i].groupzname + " - " + response.json.response.user[i].membername;   // set model value
            $scope.model.membervalue = response.json.response.user[i].membername; 
        }
            $window.localStorage.x = $scope.model.dropDownData;  //setting data in cookies

            $scope.model.displayHome = true; // variable to show and hide home and login
                         deferred.resolve(response);
                     })
                     .error(function(error) {
                         deferred.reject(error);
                     });
                 return deferred.promise;

             };     

});
}) ();
```

**app.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies'])
        .config(config)
        .run(run);

    config.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider'];
    function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                controller: 'UserDataController',
                templateUrl: 'view/home.view.html',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })

            .when('/admin', {
                controller: 'HomeController',
                templateUrl: 'view/adminhome.view.html',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })
            .when('/userdata', {
                controller: 'UserDataController',
                templateUrl: 'view/profile.view.html',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })
        .when('/login', {
                controller: 'LoginController',
                templateUrl: 'view/login.view.html',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })

            .when('/resetpassword', {
                controller: 'ResetPasswordController',
                templateUrl: 'view/resetpassword.view.html',
                controllerAs: 'vm'

            })

            .when('/resetpasswordmailsent',{
                templateUrl: 'view/resetpasswordmailsent.view.html'
        })

            .when('/setnewpassword/:id', {
                controller: 'SetNewPasswordController',
                templateUrl: 'view/setnewpassword.view.html',
                controllerAs: 'vm'    
            })

            .when('/register', {
                controller: 'RegisterController',
                templateUrl: 'view/register.view.html',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })

            .when('/afterregister', {
                templateUrl: 'view/activationlinksent.view.html'
            })

            .when('/VerifyEmail/:id', {
                controller: 'VerifyEmailController',
                templateUrl: 'view/accountactivation.view.html',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })


            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });
    }

    run.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$location', '$cookieStore', '$http'];
    function run($rootScope, $location, $cookieStore, $http) {
        // keep user logged in after page refresh
        $rootScope.globals = $cookieStore.get('globals') || {};
        $rootScope.globals = $cookieStore.get('groupzname') || {};
        if ($rootScope.globals.currentUser) {
            $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + $rootScope.globals.currentUser.authdata; // jshint ignore:line
        }

        $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
            // redirect to login page if not logged in and trying to access a restricted page
            var restrictedPage = $.inArray($location.path(), ['/login', '/resetpassword','/register','/resetpasswordmailsent','/afterregister','/setnewpassword']) === -1;
            var loggedIn = $rootScope.globals.currentUser;
            if (restrictedPage && !loggedIn) {
                $location.path('/login');
            }
        });
    }

})();
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use localstorage or cookies to retain the currentUser, You are using the $rootScope which is reloaded everytime the page is refreshed hence the login page.

use ng-storage to store the current user in localstorage after login.

Then recover it in Application.run if the `$rootScope.globals.currentUser` is null

everything else looks ok.

Comment: Do i need to use $localstorage.globals.currentUser instead of $rootScope

Comment: Its better loading it to $rootScope.globals.currentUser  if its present in localstorage  when the application starts. Then u can access it in all the controllers under $scope.globals.currentUser.